# エクセルで決まった数値のみ抽出する方法

Tags: excel

エクセルシートＡの、ある列に1から順に番号が振ってあるとします。 
エクセルシートＢの、ある列にいくつかの数値が順に振ってあるとします。 
シートＢの数値のみ、シートＡから取り出すにはどのような方法があるでしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

`VLOOKUP`とフィルタを使う方法

シートＡのＡ列に1から順に番号が振ってある（１行目は項目名として２行目から入力されている）
シートＢのＡ列にいくつかの数値が順に振ってある

シートＡのＢ列に`=VLOOKUP(A2,シートＢ!数値の範囲を絶対指定(例：$A$1:$A$10),1,FALSE)` 
を入力しフィル（Ａ列の数だけコピーする、右下をダブルクリック）
シートＢの指定範囲に無い場合`#N/A`になるので、
フィルタで等しくないで`#N/A`を設定する。